# What does File:/// mean in a file path?

Tags: file, uri, filepath

Recently been writing some code in Access VBA and learned that I needed to add 
`File:///` to get my code to work since a normal URL path didn't work.

Can someone tell me what the significance of this is:

```
File:///C:\temp
```

Tried to search the web but it was difficult to get any straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), for referring to files on the local computer or on a network share, e.g. `file://server/path/to/file.ext`.